# Create multiple substructs in loop and indexing with cellarray

Tags: matlab, struct

Let's say I have got a struct called data and I want to create three substructs called area, inhabitants and industry. These names are stored in a cellarray.
My method looks like this:

```
names={'area','inhabitants','industrie'};
for i=1:length(names)
data.(names(i)) = struct;
end
```

I get this error: "Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name."

However doing it like this works:

```
somestr = 'area';
data.(somestr) = struct;
```

That's why I tried:

```
names={'area','inhabitants','industrie'};
for i=1:length(names)
    somestr = names(i);
    data.(somestr) = struct;
end
```

But I get the same error as before.
I want to do it that way because I have to import a lot of data and want to store it in Matlab. If someone later wants to change the code it might be much easier to just change the cellarray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until the specific element of the cell is [accessed via curly braces](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html), the element will be a one-by-one `cell` and not a `char`.  So you just need curly braces:

```
names={'area','inhabitants','industrie'};
for i=1:length(names)
    data.(names{i}) = struct;
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much!